# is there a function to do on a specific keypress instead of click

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, tampermonkey

i was wondering if there is a function i could use instead of using a mouse click as i have set keybinds to whenever i press it it does it on my pc , here is my code i am using for a broswer script on tampermonkey,

```
        }
        $('.pagination.prev').on('click' , function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            setTimeout(function(){
                getPlayerDataFromSite();
            }, 500);
        });

        $('.pagination.next').on('click' , function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            setTimeout(function(){
                getPlayerDataFromSite();
            }, 500);
        });
    }
```

instead of using mouse click on the next button and previous button i would like it to use b key as previous and n key as next

thanks in advance for help really appriciate it

Comment: Use the `keypress` event.

Comment: do i just replace click with keypress then what goes after it?

Comment: Actually use [`keydown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keydown_event).

Comment: if you could help me to use keydown into the code that would be great

Comment: I did. Read what's in the link I shared.

Comment: yeh really confunsing

Answer (score 1):

Handling a 'keydown' event is rather simple.

You simply listen for the event, then check for the key you are interested in.

For example, this code listens for the keys "b" and "n":

```js
const pre = document.querySelector('pre');
pre.innerText = "";

window.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
  // console.log('keydown event:', event);
  pre.innerText += `keydown event.key: "${event.key}"\n`;
  if (event.key === 'b') {
    alert('You pressed "b"');
  } else if (event.key === 'n') {
    alert('You pressed "n"');
  }
});

document.querySelector('button').onclick = () => {pre.innerText = ""};
```

```html
<h4>Logging 'keydown' Events</h4>
<button>Clear Log</button>
<pre></pre>
```

**Consideratons**

As [Stephen P](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17300/stephen-p) mentions, there are some things to be aware of when using 'keydown' events:

- holding a key sends repeated keydown events
- non-printing keys such as Shift and Control send keydown events
- Shift+N produces uppercase N, not lowercase 'n'

Comment: Good demo! But readers should also be aware: • holding a key sends repeated keydown events, • keys such as Shift and Control send keydown events, • Shift+N = uppercase N != 'n'

Comment: @StephenP Thanks, I'll add that to the answer.